# SplitView inside ScrollView

Tags: qml, splitview

Putting `SplitView` inside `ScrollView` breaks its work: for some reason it stops responding to mouse events and therefore resizing its children by dragging the splitter becomes impossible.

```js
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ScrollView {
    width: 800

    SplitView {
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            right: parent.right
            left: parent.left
        }
        orientation: Qt.Vertical

        Repeater {
            model: 3

            Rectangle {
                SplitView.fillWidth: true
                SplitView.minimumHeight: 150
                color: "lightsteelblue"

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: "Row " + index
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: This is not the solution, but your SplitView isn't working correctly because it has no height. Try to use the SplitView without the ScrollView. You can resize the children as soon as you anchor it to the bottom or give it a height greater than its content